# how to use v-model with object?

Tags: nuxt.js

When I try to add an object to the data and bind it v-modal, I get the following error

```
Map: Expected mapDiv of type HTMLElement but was passed undefined.
```

script:

```
data() {
    return {
        test: { propertyType: "Residential" },
    };
},
```

template:

```
<Select
     v-model="test.propertyType"
     label="Property type"
     :options="options.propertyTypes"
     :validation="$v.propertyType"
     :allow-empty="false"
/>
```

options helper:

```
propertyTypes: ["Residential", "Commercial"],
```

browser console:

```
Property or method "propertyType" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Undefined 

found in

---> <VueMultiselect>
       <CustomSelect> at components/ui/Select.vue
         <Pages/applications/create.vue> at pages/applications/create.vue
           <Nuxt>
             <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
               <Root>

found in

---> <Pages/applications/create.vue> at pages/applications/create.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `options.propertyTypes` not defined in data state, just define it!

```
data() {
return {
    test: { propertyType: "Residential" },
    options: {
       propertyTypes: ["Residential", "Commercial"]
    }
};
```

},